# Wordpress how to handle custom taxonomy request with no param?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, taxonomy

I have a custom taxonomy and page, taxonmy-mytaxonomy.php, everything works fine with www.site.com/mytaxonomy/term, but without the term I get a 404 because there is no handler or page for that. What I want to do is go to the same page. I prefer not to create any dummy posts. How can I do that?

Comment: You'll need to create a page with the URL `www.site.com/mytaxonomy` or create a redirect to send that URL to `www.site.com/mytaxonomy/term`.

Comment: Here's the same question with a bit more info on the WordPress Development Exchange. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/235450/custom-taxonomy-archive-page